# jQuery - Error while hiding dropdown on change

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi actually i want to show a new dropdown according to the values in the first dropdown. Here i can show the dropdowns on select but i couldn't hide the other dropdowns, if we select some other options. So, If we select the "buyer-contact-details", we should show the lst1 dropdown. If we select "supplier-contact-details", the lst1 dropdown hide and lst2 should shown. Please Help me.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".deny-lst").on("change", function() {
    if ($(this).val() == "buyer-contact-details") {
      $(".lst1").slideDown();
    } else if ($(this).val() == "supplier-contact-details") {
      $(".lst2").slideDown();
    } else if ($(this).val() == "other-to-deny") {
      $(".lst3").slideDown();
    } else {
      $(".lst1, .lst2, lst3").slideUp();
    }
  });

  $(".lst3").on("change", function() {
    if ($(this).val() == "other") {
      $(".textarea").slideDown();
    } else {
      $(".textarea").slideUp();
    }
  });
})
```

```css
.textarea {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <select class="form-control input-md deny-lst">
    <option> Please Select </option>
    <option value="buyer-contact-details">Buyer shared their contact details</option>
    <option value="supplier-contact-details">Supplier shared their contact details</option>
    <option value="other-to-deny">Other Reason</option>
  </select>
  <select class="form-control input-md lst1" style="display:none;">
    <option> Please Select </option>
    <option>Option1</option>
    <option>Option2</option>

  </select>
  <select class="form-control input-md lst2" style="display:none;">
    <option> Please Select </option>
    <option>Option1</option>
    <option>Option2</option>

  </select>
  <select class="form-control input-md lst3" style="display:none;">
    <option> Please Select </option>
    <option>Option1</option>
    <option>Option2</option>
    <option value="other">Other</option>
  </select>
  <div class="textarea">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="comment">Comment:</label>
      <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="comment"></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are showing the dropdowns which are necessary to be shown but you are not hiding the ones which are not required. See the first line under change handler.

http://jsfiddle.net/dnr1bocv/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".deny-lst").on("change", function() {
    $(".lst1, .lst2, lst3").slideUp();
    if ($(this).val() == "buyer-contact-details") {
      $(".lst1").slideDown();
    } else if ($(this).val() == "supplier-contact-details") {
      $(".lst2").slideDown();
    } else if ($(this).val() == "other-to-deny") {
      $(".lst3").slideDown();
    } else {
      $(".lst1, .lst2, lst3").slideUp();
    }
  });

  $(".lst3").on("change", function() {
    if ($(this).val() == "other") {
      $(".textarea").slideDown();
    } else {
      $(".textarea").slideUp();
    }
  });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably how I'd do it.  I'd attach a class to the subdropdowns and subparts and slide them up when the main dropdown is changed.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".deny-lst").on("change", function() {
    $(".subdrop").slideUp();
    if ($(this).val() == "buyer-contact-details") {
      $(".lst1").slideDown();
    } else if ($(this).val() == "supplier-contact-details") {
      $(".lst2").slideDown();
    } else if ($(this).val() == "other-to-deny") {
      $(".lst3").slideDown();
    } else {
      $(".lst1, .lst2, lst3").slideUp();
    }
  });

  $(".lst3").on("change", function() {
    if ($(this).val() == "other") {
      $(".textarea").slideDown();
    } else {
      $(".textarea").slideUp();
    }
  });
})
```

```css
.textarea {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <select class="form-control input-md deny-lst">
    <option> Please Select </option>
    <option value="buyer-contact-details">Buyer shared their contact details</option>
    <option value="supplier-contact-details">Supplier shared their contact details</option>
    <option value="other-to-deny">Other Reason</option>
  </select>
  <select class="form-control input-md subdrop lst1" style="display:none;">
    <option> Please Select </option>
    <option>Option1</option>
    <option>Option2</option>

  </select>
  <select class="form-control input-md subdrop lst2" style="display:none;">
    <option> Please Select </option>
    <option>Option1</option>
    <option>Option2</option>

  </select>
  <select class="form-control input-md subdrop lst3" style="display:none;">
    <option> Please Select </option>
    <option>Option1</option>
    <option>Option2</option>
    <option value="other">Other</option>
  </select>
  <div class="textarea subdrop">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="comment">Comment:</label>
      <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="comment"></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```